# is there a way to fix 'npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE in react.js'"

Tags: npm-scripts

I'm trying to create an application using Django framework as a back-End and React.js as the front-End. the django portion works just fine, but when trying to integrate the react with my app. I get **npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2**. I am fairly new to this technology and I don't quiet understand where the error is coming from.

I tried cleaning up the cache and deleting the node_modules repo and then npm install but it didn't work. so i turn to you asking for help  skilled programmers

this the error i get:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './gentelella/frontend/src/index.js' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\finale\django-gentelella\gentelella'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! gentelella@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production ./gentelella/frontend/src/index.js --output ./gentelella/frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gentelella@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-22T10_24_53_635Z-debug.log
```

and this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gentelella",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./gentelella/frontend/src/index.js --output ./gentelella/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./gentelella/frontend/src/index.js --output ./gentelella/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your path is wrong. Try using removing the gantelella folder from the path, so this leaves 'frontend/src/index.js'.

This assumes you have structured your folders like this:
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\finale\django-gentelella\gentelella\frontend\src\index.js

Comment: tried that but sadly it didnt work, it returns the same error.